# Can I uninstall apps in Lollipop without clearing data?

Tags: applications, internal-storage, 5.1-lollipop, uninstallation

I'm paranoid when uninstalling apps because I'm under the impression that uninstalling them directly without using the "Clear Data" function on the app's page first will result in leftover files somewhere in the phone's system. So to finally get an answer, I'm asking here, in Lollipop, when I uninstall apps directly, do I not need to do "Clear Data" first?

Comment: Yeah I understand I need to use SD Maid to clear out the rest. What I'm saying is if I uninstall the app directly without clearing data, vs clearing data first before uninstalling is just the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Force stop → clear data → uninstall is the *same* as uninstalling app directly as far as removing app data is considered. It's just an extra step with no added benefit.
- Force stop option is primarily to troubleshoot apps when they misbehave
- Either method does not guarantee removal of *all app data* - you would need root to ensure that. See [Can a app store data beyond uninstallation?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/119453/can-a-app-store-data-beyond-uninstallation)

Comment: OS version has no bearing on this behaviour